# How to call a WCF service from javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have several input fields on my page. Now on button click event, I want to call a WCF service which is responsible for storing data into the database.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCreateApplyTemplate" Text="Create" Style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #fff;"
                    CssClass="btn lr-small-btn-template lr-btn-success" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return SaveMockTestData(this);" />
```

### page.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ScriptManager manager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
                ServiceReference srMockTest = new ServiceReference("~/WCFSERVICES/MockTest.svc");
                manager.Services.Add(srMockTest);

                ScriptReference dd1 = new ScriptReference("~/SvcToDb/JsMocktest.js");
                manager.Scripts.Add(dd1);
            }
        }
```

Now let me show you what is inside the file, JsMocktest.js

```
    (function (global, undefined) {
    var mocktest = {};
    var mockTestData = {};


    function SaveMockTestData(args) {

        if (args.value == "Save Template") {

            mockTestData.TemplateName = mocktest.txtTemplateName.value;
            mockTestData.TotalMarks = mocktest.txtTotalMarks.value;
            mockTestData.ExamDuration = mocktest.txtDuration.value;
            mockTestData.TotalQuestion = mocktest.txtTotQuestion.value;

            //question types
            let chkisMcq = mocktest.chkisMcq.checked;
            let txtMcqTypePostvMark = mocktest.txtMcqTypePostvMark.value;
            let txtMcqTypeNegtvMark = mocktest.txtMcqTypeNegtvMark.value;

            let chkisNonMcq = mocktest.chkisNonMcq.checked;
            let txtNonMcqTypePostvMark = mocktest.txtNonMcqTypePostvMark.value;
            let txtNonMcqTypeNegtvMark = mocktest.txtNonMcqTypeNegtvMark.value;

            var questionTypes = {
                qtype: []
            };

            if (chkisMcq) {
                questionTypes.qtype.push({
                    "isMcq": true,
                    "PostiveMarks": txtMcqTypePostvMark,
                    "NegetiveMark": txtMcqTypeNegtvMark,
                });
            }
            if (chkisNonMcq) {
                questionTypes.qtype.push({
                    "isMcq": false,
                    "PostiveMarks": txtNonMcqTypePostvMark,
                    "NegetiveMark": txtNonMcqTypeNegtvMark,
                });
            }
            debugger;
            mockTestData.TotalQuestionType = questionTypes;

            var table = $('#tableContainer').tableToJSON({
                ignoreColumns: [3]
            }
                );

            mockTestData.TotalSections = table;

            mockTestData.CalculatorTupe = mocktest.ddlCalcType.value;
            mockTestData.IsAutoSave = mocktest.chkIsAutoSave.checked;
            mockTestData.IsQuizPause = mocktest.chkCanPause.checked;
            mockTestData.IsMultilingualSupport = mocktest.chkIsMultLingual.checked;

            mockTestData.ExamInstruction = mocktest.chkExamInstruction.checked;
            mockTestData.ExamInstructionId = mocktest.ddlExamInstruction.value;
            var IMockTetst = new WcfAjaxServices.IMockTest();
            debugger;
            IMockTetst.InsertTemplateData(mockTestData, function (result, context, OnSuccess) {

            }, function (error, context, OnError) {
                //toastify("error", "ppp", "System Error", "toast-bottom-right", true);
            }, null);
        }
        return false;
    }

    global.$MockTestControlID = mocktest;
    global.SaveMockTestData = SaveMockTestData;
})(window);
```

Now here is the Service,

```
public class MockTest:IMockTest
    {
        readonly BO_MockTest _objBoMockTest = new BO_MockTest();
        BL_MockTest objBL_BusinessPartners = new BL_MockTest();
        public int InsertTemplateData(TemplateData data)
        {
            _objBoMockTest.Flag = "1";
            _objBoMockTest.TemplateName = data.TemplateName;
            _objBoMockTest.TotalMarks = data.TotalMarks;
            _objBoMockTest.ExamDuration = data.ExamDuration;
            _objBoMockTest.TotalQuestions = data.TotalQuestion;
            //_objBoMockTest.TotalQuestionTypes = data.TotalQuestionType;
            //_objBoMockTest.TotalSections = data.TotalSections;
            _objBoMockTest.CalculatorType = data.CalculatorTupe;
            _objBoMockTest.IsAutoSave = data.IsAutoSave;
            _objBoMockTest.IsQuizPause = data.IsQuizPause;
            _objBoMockTest.IsMultilingualSupport = data.IsMultilingualSupport;
            _objBoMockTest.IsContainExamInstruction = data.ExamInstruction;
            _objBoMockTest.ExamInstructionId = data.ExamInstructionId;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

here is the interface,

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "WcfAjaxServices")]
    public interface IMockTest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int InsertTemplateData(TemplateData data);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TemplateData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TotalMarks { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ExamDuration { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TotalQuestion { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string TotalQuestionType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TotalSections { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CalculatorTupe { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsAutoSave { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsQuizPause { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsMultilingualSupport { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool ExamInstruction { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ExamInstructionId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I dont have any clue how to map my json object i.e mockTestData with TemplateData and more overover 
how to call **int InsertTemplateData(TemplateData data);** this method from my javascript code..

[image]
[image]

### Edit In My Post

I just changed my WCF method like this,

```
[OperationContract]
int InsertTemplateData();
```

instead of using

```
[OperationContract]
int InsertTemplateData(TemplateData data);
```

and

```
public class MockTest:IMockTest
    {
        readonly BO_MockTest _objBoMockTest = new BO_MockTest();
        BL_MockTest objBL_BusinessPartners = new BL_MockTest();
        public int InsertTemplateData()
        {
            TemplateData data = new TemplateData();
            _objBoMockTest.Flag = "1";
            _objBoMockTest.TemplateName = data.TemplateName;
            _objBoMockTest.TotalMarks = data.TotalMarks;
            _objBoMockTest.ExamDuration = data.ExamDuration;
            _objBoMockTest.TotalQuestions = data.TotalQuestion;
            //_objBoMockTest.TotalQuestionTypes = data.TotalQuestionType;
            //_objBoMockTest.TotalSections = data.TotalSections;
            _objBoMockTest.CalculatorType = data.CalculatorTupe;
            _objBoMockTest.IsAutoSave = data.IsAutoSave;
            _objBoMockTest.IsQuizPause = data.IsQuizPause;
            _objBoMockTest.IsMultilingualSupport = data.IsMultilingualSupport;
            _objBoMockTest.IsContainExamInstruction = data.ExamInstruction;
            _objBoMockTest.ExamInstructionId = data.ExamInstructionId;
            return 12;
        }
    }
```

and called like this,

```
IMockTetst.InsertTemplateData(function (result, context, OnSuccess) {
                debugger;

            }, function (error, context, OnError) {
                //toastify("error", "ppp", "System Error", "toast-bottom-right", true);
            }, null);
```

and doing so I am getting, the result as expected. So it means there is a problem with mockTestData which I am passing from javascript and the TemplateData which is receiving it...

My question is how to map those two variables? I think there is an issue with mapping .. ?? Help needed please :)
[image]

Comment: You may refer this link [Call WCF Service from javascript](https://yaplex.com/blog/how-to-call-wcf-services-from-javascript-jquery-and-asp-net-ajax).

Comment: Can't I call that method like like what I did??Why its showing 500?

Comment: 500 means something on the server went wrong. May you can debug your server method (maybe there is an exception for example)

Comment: Actually, I cannot able to pass my javascript object to that service. If I modify the code for testing i.e changing the Method signature, int EmptyCSParameterMethod() and Call this method from javascript then code is executing perfectly. My concern is how could I pass my data to that Service?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have resolved the issue that how to call WCF service from the Javascript code. The rest problem is how can we pass the parameter to method when using a JSON object.
Please refer to the example.

```
    <script>
        function Calculate() {
            var product = { "Name": "apple", "Amount": 3, "Price": 4.23 };
            CostService.CostOfProducts(product, function (result) {
                console.log(result)
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Content/CostService.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            Calculate the total prices of the Products.
        </div>
             <input type="button" value="Price of 3 sandwiches" onclick="Calculate()" />
        <br />
        <span id="additionResult"></span>
    </form>
</body>
```

**SVC file.**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CostService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public double CostOfProducts(Product product)
        {
            return product.Amount * product.Price;
        }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Ok, @Abraham Qian sir, let me try it and I will let you know that for sure.